# Chromatic number of a subgraph of a random graph

Tags: probability, random-graphs

Suppose that we have a random graph G(n,p) with $n$ vertices and each edge exists with probability $p = n^{-\alpha}, \alpha>\frac{5}{6}$. Prove that with high probability, say $1-\delta$, every subgraph with $o(\sqrt{n})$ vertices has a chromatic number equal to 3.

This is the first part of a problem that I'm stuck at it.

Comment: Is this a step in the proof of two-point concentration of the chromatic number $\chi(G(n,p))$?

Comment: @MishaLavrov It is the first step in the proof of a concentration for the chromatic number. What do you mean by two-point?

Comment: By two-point I mean the result that for some range of $p$ (I do not remember which) the chromatic number has one of two values with high probability.

Comment: @MishaLavrov In my problem it was asked to prove $u\le\chi(G)\le u+3$ with high probability.

Comment: That's also pretty good! The $u \le \chi(G) \le u+1$ result can be found in [this paper by Luczak](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~tomasz/papers/sharp.ps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $k$, the expected number of sets of $k$ vertices with at least $\frac32k$ edges between them is no more than
$$
   \binom nk \binom{\binom k2}{\frac32 k} p^{\frac32k} \le \binom nk \binom{\frac12 k^2}{\frac32 k} p^{\frac32k}.
$$
Using the inequality $\binom nk \le \left(\frac{ne}{k}\right)^k$, we can show that when $k \le \sqrt n$, this is bounded by $f(n)^k$ for some function $f(n)$ such that $f(n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. (Try this!) In particular, if we sum over all $k \le \sqrt n$, the sum is bounded by $\frac{f(n)}{1-f(n)}$, which is still tending to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

So with high probability, there are no sets of $k\le \sqrt n$ vertices with $\frac32k$ edges between them: in other words, the average degree of any subgraph on at most $\sqrt n$ vertices is less than $3$.

Then we can $3$-color any such subgraph by choosing a vertex $v$ of degree $2$, removing it, coloring the rest inductively, and putting $v$ back in with a color different from either of its neighbors.